# MinGW lib files

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

Where can I download MinGW with `.lib` library files instead `.a`? Or maybe I can build it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what would you do with `.lib` files?

Comment: I have a project with makefile wich needs this .lib files and I'm trying to build it.

Comment: Post the makefile here. You can probably edit it to use the .a files.

Comment: As Neil suggests. You can probably implement it as a macro so that you only need to edit one line to convert all ".lib" to ".a", which will make it easier to switch between compilers. Alternatively, rename the files, since it doesn't matter whether they're .lib or .a, they still have the same content - the extension is just there to find them in the filesystem.